Using FOSS extensions from Google Web Store outside of Chrome
Is it legal to use a FOSS extension from Google Web Store without registration in ungoogled Chromium or other FOSS browsers?

Are you happy to restrict this question to only FOSS extensions? Asking about non-FOSS works is off-topic here, but you could move this to Law SE if you want that.


Are you happy to restrict this question to only FOSS extensions? -- Yeah, fine. Thanks for quick reply.


Hi @user34196, I've edited your question to match the exchange in the comments above -- feel free to edit or add more information/examples if you want, especially if I've accidentally misrepresented your question with my edits (but I hope I haven't).

Yes.  The first of the four freedoms of free software is the "freedom to run the program as you wish, for any purpose".  A licence restriction on an extension that it could only be used with, say, Chromium, would make it un-free, and thus outside the remit of this question.  Similarly, a licence restriction on a browser that limited it to using extensions from a specific source would make it, too, non-free.  If both are free, the practice is absolutely fine.
Whether this would work from a technical standpoint is a different question, and one not appropriate for this site.
